# Haskell Beginner Error with GHCi

Tags: haskell

I'm on my Mac trying out Haskell and to my surprise, when I defined a function, I got an error:

```
Prelude System.IO> :set prompt "ghci> "
ghci> addMe :: Int -> Int -> Int

<interactive>:11:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: addMe :: Int -> Int -> Int
ghci>
```

How can I define functions on the ghci?

Comment: Use multiline input or explicit semicolons, as demonstrated in [*Function definiton by special cases in GHCi*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42593284/2751851).

Comment: I find it easier to put all definitions in a file I then `:load` into ghci.

Comment: Consider also [IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell), which combines the direct-feedback experience of typing directly in the interpreter with the structure and backup capabilities of a proper source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a type signature to a definition in GHCi, you can specify it by using multiline input through `:set +m` or `:{ ... :}`, as described in the [GHC Users Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#using-do-notation-at-the-prompt), or by using semicolons, as in:

```
mulme x y = [x*y| x /= 0, y/= 0]; mulme :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

Comment: Note that we generally use `Maybe` instead of lists that will always have at most one element. By doing it that way, the right-hand side of the definition above might become `if (x /= 0 && y /= 0) then Just (x * y) else Nothing`.